# php $_SESSION['post_vars'][$key] = $value; - undefined variable: key, value

Tags: php, error-reporting

I have been debugging a series of errors since switching to strict error reporting.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

I have managed to correct all but two errors by using the isset function e.g.

```
$message = isset( $_GET['message'] )? $_GET['message']: "";
```

But I'm not sure how to fix this which gives Undefined variable: key and Undefined variable: variable errors.

```
$_SESSION['post_vars'][$key] = $value;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. And also make sure that your using $key and $value variables after defining them.

```
if(empty($_SESSION['post_vars'])){
 $_SESSION['post_vars'] = array();
}
```

Comment: I followed a tutorial, it doesn't appear as if key or value are used later in the script. Can you explain what is happening here (your code)? On post the variables are held in an array?

Comment: @raybarone In that case you can define $key and $value variables with null values before using them. Something like $key = empty( $_GET['key'] )? $_GET['key']: "";

Comment: The form seems to be working fine. It's for editing stored data so I'm not really sure why $key and $value were used.

Comment: @raybarone You'll need to post more code in order for me to figure out the exact source of the problem.

Comment: Thanks but I've tested it several times without key or value declared and the edits are saved, I've checked the data in phpmyadmin. I'm not sure why they were included in the first place.